# Misplaced columns headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` that has a 3 columns , one of them(ObjectiveID) is `invisible` using the **CSS**:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

But, when i use this style, i got **misplaced columns headers** as shown in the picture below :

[image]

My Aspx code:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdPlanObjectivesStandardWeights" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive table-striped"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="tableHeader"
            DataKeyNames="ObjectiveID"
            EmptyDataText="<%$Resources:DCAACommon, NoDataMessage%>"
            EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="alert alert-warning"
            EmptyDataRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ObjectiveID">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:DCAAStrategicManagement, Initiative_ObjectiveName  %>" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:DCAAStrategicManagement, obj_lblStandardWeight  %>" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStandardWeight" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers();" Text='<%# Eval("StandardWeight") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-gridView" />
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Note: i need to keep the **ObjectiveID** invisible, and i must not use **Visible="False"** to the BoundField.

Any help would be appreaciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to hide only the `items` , all i needed is to also hide the Header.

So, i have changed this :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ObjectiveID">
     <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

To this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ObjectiveID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden"/>
```

And it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding a `<td>` item, not it's content. This will lead to weird behaviour.

A solution is to change the `BoundField` to a `TemplateField`. You'll have more control that way.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("ObjectiveID") %></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<style type="text/css">
    .hidden span {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I already have a solution to my problem but, i think this will reasonably works.